# ActiveAndroid how to get single column items from table and store those in arraylist

Tags: android, activeandroid

I am new to active android, i have a table named MyTable with columns articleName, articleId and imageTicket, i want to store all imageTicket column values in a ArrayList. can anyone help me with a query?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code to get imageTicket column from MyTable

```
 private ArrayList<MyTable> myTableList = new ArrayList<MyTable>();
 // to get all table data
 myTableList =  new Select().from(MyTable.class).execute();

 for(int i = 0; i < myTableList.size(); i++){         
     String imageTicket = myTableList.get(i).getImageTicket();
     // do something with imageticket value
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this :
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

```
// 2. build query
Cursor cursor = 
        db.query(TABLE_NAME, // a. table
        COLUMNS, // b. column names
        " id = ?", // c. selections 
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
        null, // e. group by
        null, // f. having
        null, // g. order by
        null); // h. limit
```

for more info : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/activeandroid-guide... this link would be helpful